# Trying to hide a div based on url with ng-if

Tags: angularjs

I have a view with a div:

```
<div ng-if="location.path() != '/xyz'">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

In the controller for this file I have injected the $location service.

Yet when I go to the url '/xyz' the div gets shown. What could be wrong?

Comment: Glad you found the bug because it was hard for us to help with so few info...

Answer (score 0):

I need to add the $location service to the $scope in the controller to make this work.